# change BackGround color of specific elements in a listView (JavaFx)

Tags: java, javafx

i'm working on a project and i'd like to find a way to change the background color of some elements in a listView. i've find a way to add css style class to the listView in general but not to specific elements .

Also , i've heard about cell factory but I dont know if cell factory can adapt during the programme or just set up things at the begging

(i have a listView of an object that I call player , and I want that , when the player in the listView get enough points , his name becomes red)

is there a way to do something like this ?

```java
ListView<Players> listview = ...;
for(Player p : listView){
   p.addListener(//change color to red)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you please specify your question more? Which specific element are you wanting to change? Why are you adding a listener if you just want to change specific listView's colour?

Comment: i have a game , and I've a listView a the player in the game, and i'd like to change the color of the Player representation in the list when one of their attributs get to a specific value , the listener was just an exemple , i dont know how to do it .

Comment: work through a tutorial on how to use ListView - you need a custom listCell that configures itself based on some state of the data (== player) item that's visualized in it

Answer (score -2):

I would use [ObservableList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) and **addListener** to the given List.

Sample code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {
    private StackPane main;
    private ListView<Player> players;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        main = new StackPane();

        var scene = new Scene(main, 640, 480);

        players = new ListView<Player>();
        ObservableList<Player> playerObjs = FXCollections.observableArrayList (
                new Player("A", 50),
                new Player("B", 30),
                new Player("C", 60),
                new Player("D", 5),
                new Player("E", 0)
        );
        players.setItems(playerObjs);
        playerObjs.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Player>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<? extends Player> change) {
                updateView();
            }
        });

        main.getChildren().add(players);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void updateView() {
        for(int i = 0; i < players.getItems().size(); i++) {
            if(players.getItems().get(i).getHp() < 10) {
                players.getItems().get(i).setBackground(...);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Now, everytime the list changes, it calls **updateView()**, which if some condition holds, will set the given item Background to some value.

Let me know if that helped.

Comment: most probably not (though not entirely impossible ;) ... the data item should not hold any visual state like background (yours correctly doesn't), instead it should have have some domain state like f.i. health. And no, there is no need to update the view manually (here call updateView) provided the data/view is wired correctly (configure the observableList with an extractor and implement a custom cell that configures its background based on health points)